# OnMouse Events stop working when multiple cameras are active

Tags: unity, events

I'm working on 2019.4.9f1 on a 2D project using Universal Rendering Pipeline. The camera settings changed so I'm stating it.

I wrote a `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseExit` in a script to manage whenever my mouse cursor is on top of a SpriteRenderer with a collider located at `0,0,0`. I have a main camera located at `0,0,-10`. I've tested the script that manages the `OnMouse` events. It works fine.

**Problem**: But the moment I add a new camera (UI Camera set to Overlay located at `0,0,-10`) in and it is enabled, `OnMouse` events aren't getting called. Disabling the UI camera makes the `OnMouse` events work normally.

**Solutions that have failed:**

1. I've tried setting the tag of the UI Camera to `MainCamera` and set
   Main Camera's tag to `Default`.
   https://answers.unity.com/questions/241334/onmousedown-w-multiple-cameras-doesnt-work-right.html
2. I tried making the UI Camera a bit closer to the sprites.
   https://answers.unity.com/questions/425478/onmousedown-not-firing.html

**I intend to avoid Raycasting and get the `OnMouse` Events to work because I want to fix the problem and not work around it.**

**Question**: Any possible reason why my OnMouse events aren't called?

Comment: "I intend to avoid Raycasting" I have some bad news for you about how the OnMouse events work then. They're still raycasting under the hood, they're just using the most inefficient raycast possible because the engine can't guess what you want and has to cover the widest possible set of use cases. Removing your OnMouse events and firing your own ray will allow you to get finer control over how the events are called and the performance of the testing.

Comment: I see. I guess it can't be helped. Though, how can I reliably check for a 2D object that is directly below my cursor. I've checked https://answers.unity.com/questions/596792/raycast-on-a-2d-collider.html and it says to add a 3D collider for a raycast to work. is this necessary or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Presumably you considered [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) and [Physics2D.OverlapPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapPoint.html)?

Comment: Oh. Just tested `ScreenToWorldPoint` while I scrolled through the link. this works. didn't know they existed.

Comment: For future reference, I'm adding the issue tracker for this problem here (tldr there's no formal solution but a few workarounds): https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/urp-onmouse-methods-are-not-called-when-using-camera-stacking-with-different-culling-masks

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for those interested.

Before setting your overlay camera to overlay, head to rendering - priority, and set to a number lower than your main camera. After that, you may change render type back to overlay.

OR

Simply set main camera priority to a higher number.

Comment: This solution worked best in my case as well.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here, my setup is

- base camera with two overlays
- one of them is rendering only UI (UICamera)
- the UI Canvas render mode is "Screen Space - Camera" and the Render Camera is set to the UICamera

in my case the solution was to set the Canvas "Plane distance" greater then 0
(actually i guess something greater needed than the camera clipping plane near value)

hope this helps someone too